# How to get the internet working on Raspberry pi connected to a PC through an ethernet cable?

Tags: iptables, gateway

I am trying the following setup:

Raspberry pi (eth0) <--> (eth0) laptop (wlan0) <--> Internet

(The raspberry has a Raspbian.). Left-hand side LAN uses addresses 192.168.0.*.

I am currently running the following script on the laptop:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth0 inet 192.168.0.1
route | grep "192\.168\.0\.0" || \
 route add -net 192.168.0.0/16 dev eth0

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -F; iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

killall -9 udhcpd
udhcpd -f
```

hoping that the (almost out-of-the-box) Raspbian on the Raspberry will pick up the DHCP server. (In the final configuration the Raspberry will be in a headless setup).

However, this only works *sometimes*. When pinging one of the two machines from the other I also often have `Packet filtered` answers, or none at all. (Also, it looks like the laptop sometimes drops the route that I added).

What did I forget?

Comment: `eth0`'s network is 192.168.0.0/16. You want to NAT packets going out from the `wlan0` interface with a  192.168.0.0/16 source address, right? So, why use a `! -d 192.168.0.0/16` condition? Should be `-s 192.168.0.0/16` in my opinion. BTW, what is the `wlan0` network?

Comment: And BTW, I don't see what all this has to do with DHCP. If you want your laptop's DHCP server to provide an address to your Pi, just make it listen on eth0 and configure it properly.

Comment: Assign another IP address to your `eth0` maybe you are using the router IP. Use `/24` instead of `/16`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do doesn't work this way. You can't have overlapping IP ranges on two different network interfaces: As you have found out, this will sometimes deliver packets, and sometimes not. And DHCP requests are broadcasts that are restricted to a single LAN segment, they won't be forwarded.

If the PC was connected via LAN to the internet instead of WLAN, you could just bridge the two `ethX` interfaces. But you can't bridge a WLAN interface to LAN, unless the WLAN is in 4-address mode, because ordinary 3-address WLAN packets don't carry enough information so you can both address the PC as "intermediate" receiver, and the RaspPi as "final" receiver.

So the proper way to do it is to assign different IP ranges on both interfaces, e.g. 192.168.1.*/24 (or whatever your router gives you) on `wlan0`, and 192.168.3.1/24 (or whatever) on `eth0` on the laptop. Then run a DHCP server on the laptop that controls `eth0` and gives the RaspPi a 192.168.55.*/24 address. Finally, enable forwarding and masquerading.

I use the following script for that on my PC, with a proper dhcpd config file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# pass eth0 through wlan0, using nat

modprobe nf_conntrack
modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
modprobe nf_nat
modprobe iptable_nat  

EXTIF="wlan0"
INTIF="eth0"

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD 
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE

ip link set eth0 down
ip addr flush dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.3.1/24 dev eth0
ip link set eth0 up

/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
```

(Replace last line with a systemd command to start the DHCP server if you use systemd).